# PHP | How to read file lines with 'for'?

Tags: php

Instead of simple numbers 1-10,

I want to take information from a .txt file from the beginning of the file to the end, and go through it in the loop.

Example of txt file:

sport

news

cartoon

I want the loop to be like that:

http://website.com/sport

http://website.com/news

http://website.com/cartoon

```
$file = "readinfo.txt";


for($i=1;$i<=10;$i++){

    $content[$i] = @get_file("http://website.com/$i");


    if($content[$i]===FALSE){
        echo "Error getting ('.$i.')<br>";
        return;
    }else{
        echo "Got ('.$i.')<br>";
    }
    ob_flush();
    _flush();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`file`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) function will read a file into an array, e.g.

```
$file = "readinfo.txt";

$lines = file($file, FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
  ...
}
```

The `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag is used to trim the new-line character(s) from the end of the lines, since all you're interested in are the individual words.

Depending on your file, you might also want to use the `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` flag.

Comment: Yes, its great! thank you! 5min and i vote! It is written in red to wait

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
     $file = file_get_contents('readinfo.txt', true);
     $exp=explode("\n", $file);
     foreach($exp as $value){
         echo $value."\n"; // this is one row
     }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use a foreach?

```
$filename = 'readinfo.txt';
$i = 0;
$contents = file($filename);

foreach($contents as $line) {
    $content[$i] = "http://website.com/".$line;
    $i = $i + 1;
}
```